# Why does my python TCP server need to bind to 0.0.0.0 and not localhost or it's IP address?

Tags: c#, python, sockets, tcp

I'm making a Python TCP server and a C# client, and I got it to work, but I don't understand *why* it's working and I'm hoping someone can explain to me what I'm missing. I'm trying to connect from within my own network, so there are no firewalls involved.

In my python script, if I bind to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` I cannot connect to it from my C# script, so I thought maybe it needs to be the local IP address that the DHCP server gives it, so I tried binding to `192.168.1.74` (the local IP address). That still didn't work, *however* if I use `0.0.0.0` as the port I bind to, I am able to connect without a problem.

Python Server Code:

```
def startserver():
    global serversocket
    global server

    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serversocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8089))
    #limit connections to 1 because we only expect C# code to talk to us
    serversocket.listen(1)
    print("Server Started, await connections...")
```

C# TCPclient Code:

```
public string host = "192.168.1.74";
public int port = 8089;

public void ConnectSocket(string server, int port)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    print(string.Format("Sent: {0}", "Hellow World"));
    data = new byte[256];

    string responseData = string.Empty;

    int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    print(string.Format("Received: {0}", responseData));

    stream.Close();
    client.Close();
}
```

Why does it only work with `0.0.0.0`?

**EDIT**: After binding to `0.0.0.0` and connecting, I can now bind to it's IP address (`192.168.1.74`) and connect. Though `0.0.0.0` allows me to connect via `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` so I think I'll keep using it.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a special value that says "Bind to all interfaces in the system" (only IPv4)-- loopback, ethernet, etc. In Python you can also pass an empty string instead of `"0.0.0.0"`.

Comment: I guess a better question would be, is this the *proper* way to bind the TCP server? Or should I try and bind it to a specific interface? This script is also connected to a NodeJS server running locally over TCP, so IMO `0.0.0.0` allowing it to bind to all interfaces is correct, but wanna make sure I'm doing things correctly then.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 for IPv4 or ::0 for IPv6 is commonly used as wildcard address. If you use localhost, then check the DNS result to see which IP address (might be 127.0.0.1) is in fact bind to. When such an address is used, your client must connect to that IP address explicitly, such as 127.0.0.1, not 192.182.x.x. That's a computer network basic concept.

Comment: You mention "I tried binding to 192.168.1.74" but in the C# code the IP address  is different, 192.168.180.132

Comment: @J.J.Hakala that was an oversight of copy pasting everything. It's correct in the actual code. I can connect by binding to the IP address now though. But it didn't work until I tried `0.0.0.0` so Don't know if I made a typo previously, or if it was something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

127.0.0.1 and localhost (which are basically the same), are 'local loopback' addresses. This means that they can only be accessed from your computer. Any other computer (even on your own network) cannot connect to them. This might also also depend on your operating system.

To be able to connect to the server within your own network, I think you can use 0.0.0.0, or your local IP address. You can find it in Windows with `ipconfig`, and in Linux (I think in MAC too) with `ifconfig`. It will most likely look something like "192.168.a.b", but that depends a bit on the configuration of your network.

Comment: Just going to confirm your statement that using `0.0.0.0` allows me to connect over `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.1.74`, but if I bind to a specific IP, I **have** to use that same IP no matter where else I am connecting from. e.g. if I run another client on the same machine while I'm bound to `192.168.1.74` I cannot use `localhost`, I have to use the same IP.

Comment: Yes, you do need to use the exact IP that the server is listening on. If you want to listen on both localhost and 192.168.1.74, you'll need to either use 0.0.0.0 or create multiple sockets.

Comment: localhost can be 127.0.0.1, but DNS settings can made it other values, ::0 or another. So don't make assumptions and always check the DNS resolution.